# What skill or spell do I use to remove the immobilize/frozen effect in Torchlight 2?

Tags: torchlight-2

I'm playing a dual-wielding, level 28 berserker. Had a few close calls got immobilized. What skills or spells can I add to avoid or getting immobilized?

[Link to my current skills](http://tidbi.ru/eng/berserker.php?lvl=28&fm=8&skill=080010014000010000015550000050&stat=aaapafafafaaaaaa).